# How can I change an EPOCH time starting on a particular day at a particular time to that same day but midnight?

Tags: python, epoch

I have the following code below, which converts a human-readable date into an EPOCH datetime. However, the EPOCH date time is for 2022/09/15 4pm to 2022/09/16 4pm. Is it possible to change it so that it produces the EPOCH for 2022/09/15 12:00am to 2022/09/16 12:00am?

```
import datetime as dt  

(dt.datetime(2022, 9, 15).timestamp(), dt.datetime(2022, 9, 16).timestamp()-1)
```

Output:
(1663171200.0, 1663257599.0)

Comment: Those actually are the timestamps for midnight. Why do you think they're for 4pm? Do you have a particular timezone in mind? (UTC-8 apparently.)

Comment: I am working with GTM- should have mentioned

Comment: Sorry, what's GTM? Google Tag Manager? Or do you mean GMT-8?